# arm-unknown-linux-gnu-gcc: error trying to exec 'cc1': execvp: No such file or directory

Tags: arm

I have configur eclipse Neon in windows and tried to compile code related to a POS device but i get error the code is:

```
13:49:58 **** Incremental Build of configuration Debug for project DemoApps ****
Info: Internal Builder is used for build
"C:\\POS\\glibc-oabi-toolchain-arm-generic\\bin\\arm-unknown-linux-gnu-gcc" "-IC:\\POS\\sdk\\sdk_8210\\include" "-IC:\\POS\\sdk\\sdk_8210\\include\\directfb" -O0 -g3 -Wall -Wundef -Wstrict-prototypes -Werror-implicit-function-declaration -Wdeclaration-after-statement -fsigned-char -marm -mapcs -mno-sched-prolog -mabi=apcs-gnu -mlittle-endian -mno-thumb-interwork -msoft-float -c -o "src\\DemoApps.o" "..\\src\\DemoApps.c" 
arm-unknown-linux-gnu-gcc: error trying to exec 'cc1': execvp: No such file or directory

13:49:58 Build Finished (took 301ms)
```

Comment: It can't find `cc1` (a part of the GCC toolchain). Add `C:\POS\glibc-oabi-toolchain-arm-generic\bin` to your `PATH`.

Comment: as you said i changed path. now i have another error: Program "C:\POS\glibc-oabi-toolchain-arm-generic\bin" not found in PATH DemoApps

Comment: Is `cc1` actually there in that `bin` directory?

Comment: no any directory or file in this name in the directory

Comment: Sounds like a busted toolchain to me.

Comment: I could find 'cc1' file in **C:\glibc-oabi-toolchain-arm-generic\libexec\gcc\arm-unknown-linux-gnu\4.3.4** folder

Comment: And did you try adding `C:\glibc-oabi-toolchain-arm-generic\libexec\gcc\arm-unknown-‌​linux-gnu\4.3.4` to the `PATH`, too?

Comment: How can i add this path. please instruct me. i'm new to here

Comment: It's just an environment variable, you set it in your OS (remember the `;` separator). See for example the steps used [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9546324/adding-directory-to-path-environment-variable-in-windows), or Google how to set `PATH` on Windows. Then restart Eclipse.

Comment: i have set environment variable and project build again. but the problem is not solved

Comment: I  know this is an old  post. I am also facing this issue. Have anyone fixed this issue?